# setText not working to set the date

Tags: android

This is the main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
EditText doa,et;
Context context;
ImageView calender,cam;
CalendarView cal;
Button save, nexto, can;
TextView Area, timedisplay;
EditText areaEnter;
int m = 0, n = 0, o = 0, p = 0, res = 0, sonal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    can = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_action);
    nexto=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
  //  doa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activitydateswati);
    et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.activitydateswati);
    cam=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.camera);
    calender = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.calimg);
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==              Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.content_landscape);
    }

    Spinner activitysector=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selectactivitysector);
    activitysector.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> categories2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories2.add("Select Activity Sector");
    categories2.add("Domestic Sector Activities");
    categories2.add("Agriculture Sector Activities");
    categories2.add("Transport Sector Activities");
    categories2.add("Industry Sector Activities");
    categories2.add("Miscellaneous Activities");
    categories2.add("PAT");
    categories2.add("ISO 50001");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories2);
    dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    activitysector.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    //

    Spinner fromhr=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.fromhour);
    fromhr.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> categories3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories3.add("00");
    categories3.add("01");
    categories3.add("02");
    categories3.add("03");
    categories3.add("04");
    categories3.add("05");
    categories3.add("06");
    categories3.add("07");
    categories3.add("08");
    categories3.add("09");
    categories3.add("10");
    categories3.add("11");
    categories3.add("12");
    categories3.add("13");
    categories3.add("14");
    categories3.add("15");
    categories3.add("16");
    categories3.add("17");
    categories3.add("18");
    categories3.add("19");
    categories3.add("20");
    categories3.add("21");
    categories3.add("22");
    categories3.add("23");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterdatefromhour = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories3);
    dataAdapterdatefromhour.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    fromhr.setAdapter(dataAdapterdatefromhour);

    Spinner frommin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.from_minutes);
    frommin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> categoriesfromminutes = new ArrayList<String>();
    categoriesfromminutes.add("00");
    categoriesfromminutes.add("15");
    categoriesfromminutes.add("30");
    categoriesfromminutes.add("45");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterdatefrommin = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categoriesfromminutes);
    dataAdapterdatefrommin.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    frommin.setAdapter(dataAdapterdatefrommin);

    Spinner tohr=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.tohour);
    tohr.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> categoriestohour = new ArrayList<String>();
    categoriestohour.add("00");
    categoriestohour.add("01");
    categoriestohour.add("02");
    categoriestohour.add("03");
    categoriestohour.add("04");
    categoriestohour.add("05");
    categoriestohour.add("06");
    categoriestohour.add("07");
    categoriestohour.add("08");
    categoriestohour.add("09");
    categoriestohour.add("10");
    categoriestohour.add("11");
    categoriestohour.add("12");
    categoriestohour.add("13");
    categoriestohour.add("14");
    categoriestohour.add("15");
    categoriestohour.add("16");
    categoriestohour.add("17");
    categoriestohour.add("18");
    categoriestohour.add("19");
    categoriestohour.add("20");
    categoriestohour.add("21");
    categoriestohour.add("22");
    categoriestohour.add("23");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterdatetohour = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categoriestohour);
    dataAdapterdatetohour.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    tohr.setAdapter(dataAdapterdatetohour);

    Spinner tomin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.tominutes);
    tomin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> categoriestominutes = new ArrayList<String>();
    categoriestominutes.add("00");
    categoriestominutes.add("15");
    categoriestominutes.add("30");
    categoriestominutes.add("45");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterdatetomin = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categoriestominutes);
    dataAdapterdatetomin.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    tomin.setAdapter(dataAdapterdatetomin);
}


public void popupimage(View v) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater
            = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 400, 400, true);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable (new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
    cal = (CalendarView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    cal.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            et.setText(year + "-" + month + "-" + dayOfMonth);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, et.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String a="",b="",c="",d="";

    switch (parent.getId())
    {

        case R.id.selectactivitysector: String item2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Spinner subactivity =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selectactivity);
            List<String> subcategories=new ArrayList<String>();
            if(item2.equalsIgnoreCase("select activity sector"))
            {

                subcategories.add("Select Activity");
            }
            else if(item2.equalsIgnoreCase("Domestic Sector Activities"))
            {
                subcategories.add("Select Activity");
                subcategories.add("Workshop Domestic");
                subcategories.add("Youth Programme");
                subcategories.add("Misc");
            }

            else if(item2.equalsIgnoreCase("Agriculture Sector Activities"))
            {
                subcategories.add("Select Activity");
                subcategories.add("Kisan Shop");
                subcategories.add("Workshop Agriculture");
                subcategories.add("Misc");
            }

            else if(item2.equalsIgnoreCase("Transport Sector Activities"))
            {
                subcategories.add("Select Activity");
                subcategories.add("Driver Training Programme");
                subcategories.add("Model Training Programme");
                subcategories.add("Training for DTI");
                subcategories.add("Workshop Transport");
                subcategories.add("Misc");
            }

            else if(item2.equalsIgnoreCase("Industry Sector Activities"))
            {
                subcategories.add("Select Activity");
                subcategories.add("Energy Audit(IH)");
                subcategories.add("Follow up");
                subcategories.add("Fuel Oil Diagnostic Study");
                subcategories.add("Institutional Training Programme");
                subcategories.add("Seminar/Technical/Consumer Meet");
                subcategories.add("Service to Small Scale Industry");
                subcategories.add("Workshop-Industrial");
                subcategories.add("Misc");
            }

            else if(item2.equalsIgnoreCase("Miscellaneous Activities"))
            {
                subcategories.add("Select Activity");
                subcategories.add("Exhibition");
                subcategories.add("Van Publicity");
                subcategories.add("Misc");
            }

            else if(item2.equalsIgnoreCase("pat"))
            {
                subcategories.add("Select Activity");
                subcategories.add("PAT");
            }
            else if(item2.equalsIgnoreCase("ISO 50001"))
            {
                subcategories.add("Select Activity");
                subcategories.add("ISO 50001");
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subcategories);
            dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            subactivity.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
            break;
        case R.id.fromhour:a=  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            m=Integer.parseInt(a);
            break;

        case R.id.from_minutes:b=  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            n=Integer.parseInt(b);

            break;

        case R.id.tohour:c=  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            o=Integer.parseInt(c);
            break;

        case R.id.tominutes:d=  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            p=Integer.parseInt(d);
            break;

    }

}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView < ? > parent){

}

public void onsaveClick(View v) {
    Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Dactivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
public void oncamClick(View v) {

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
}


}
```

This is the Xml which has spinners and editText(Code works if I have edittext and popup but when I am adding spinners and more textboxes it is not showing the desired result)
And popup.xml has only CalendarView which is working

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date of Activity*  "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/dateofactivity"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/activitydateswati"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateofactivity"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dateofactivity"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:inputType="date"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat"/>
        <!--android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"-->

    <ImageView android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar1"
        android:id="@+id/calimg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="popupimage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activitydateswati"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/activitydateswati" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Duration*  "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calimg"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dateofactivity"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/dateofactivity"
        android:id="@+id/duration"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Frm"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateofactivity"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dateofactivity" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fromhour"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textfromhrs"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calimg" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hrs"
        android:id="@+id/textfromhrs"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fromhour"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fromhour" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/from_minutes"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textfromhrs"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textfromhrs"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textfromhrs"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="mins"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/textfrommins"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/from_minutes"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/from_minutes"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="To"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tohour"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textfromhrs"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textfromhrs"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="hrs"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tohour"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textfromhrs"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textfromhrs"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tominutes"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/from_minutes"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/from_minutes"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="mins"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tominutes"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textfrommins"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textfrommins"
        android:id="@+id/textView11" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hours Invested"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView8" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No&apos;s Participated* "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:hint="Number participated"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activitydateswati"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/activitydateswati"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/calimg"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/calimg" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Region"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView14" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="SR"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activity Selector"
        android:id="@+id/textsas"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/selectactivitysector"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:id="@+id/selectactivitysector"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_weight="0.57" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="142dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:text="Activity"
        android:id="@+id/textselectactivity"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <Spinner
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        android:id="@+id/selectactivity"
        android:layout_column="9"
        android:layout_weight="0.84" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Brief Description"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="60.33"
        android:hint="(Provide description within 50 words)"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/camera">

        <Button android:text="Save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:id="@+id/save"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>


        <Button
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:onClick="onsaveClick" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>


        <Button android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cancel_action"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:src="@drawable/camera"
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView12"
            android:onClick="oncamClick" />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Date"
            android:id="@+id/sonal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Comment: "is not working" means no text is displayed or an error is thrown?

Comment: No text is displayed

Comment: But when I am trying getText after setting text I can see the date in toast or Log

Comment: ok , show us Your xml layout, I guess You have set some wrong attributes...

Comment: Did you try creating a sample textview instead of edittext and set its text?

Comment: I tried TextView also

Answer (score 0):

Use following method for showing popup and set selected date on EditText.

```
private void showDatePicker() {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService
          (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout, null, false);
CalendarView cv = (CalendarView) ll.getChildAt(0);
cv.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        edt.setText(year+"-"+month+"-"+dayOfMonth);  
    }
});
new AlertDialog.Builder(MomAppActivity.this)
.setTitle("Event Calendar")
.setMessage("Click to schedule or view events.")
.setView(ll)
.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        //do nothing...yet
    }
}).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
).show();


}
```

Comment: I want CalendarView not datepicker

Comment: Check my edited answer if works and log or toast whatever you are setting as editetext setText

Comment: What you get in toast or tag imean for year month and date value what you get?

Comment: I am getting date 2016-2-1

Comment: The code is working alone but when combined with spinners it is not working

Comment: If all is fine in code than it May be silly mistake make sure your background of edittext and textcolor not be same by default. sorry but Not got your point what the exactly you want to say

Comment: The function is working if I have just one edittext but when i have more components like spinners it shows nothing. I even tried a TextView but it is showing the same result

Comment: That's not possible alone function is working and with other widget its not work its smell wrong lemme check your xml may be you going wrong paste your full code of related xml and java in question.

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered same problem but I changed the custom background color the text is showed. Try to change the background or try set different text colors.